# I want to build manual camera2 app for android using MVP design pattern. How?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-camera, mvp

What class separation there would be? Where to place `CameraDevice`, `ImageReader`, `CameraCaptureSession`, `CaptureRequest.Builder` instances?
I guess **View** would include `Activity` and what about **Presenter** and **Model**? 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it is as simple as MVC is but **Presenter** should also include all events from UI like buttons and tables. Presenter is an arbitrator between Model and View.

> **View** are Activities
>
> **Model** are data kept in RAM or files
>
> **Presenter** are controllers(arbitrators) including all events you will handle

In your case, 
**View** is a camera preview and UIs.

**Model** are all parameters about Camera2 API

**Presenter** are all actions changing the parameters(**Model**) using UI like buttons(**View**)

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite (https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android) repo using MVP architecture so could you please give me some insights on how can I achieve it or any reference links that can help me. I tried searching but wasn't able to find any camera 2 api implementation using MVP.